# Some1 know why my listview data is not changing?

Tags: android

My `listview` gets filled on the start but after i cant find a way to make changes
pls see the code bellow

```
 public class myFragment  extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
    {


 ListView list;

ArrayList<String> restorants=new ArrayList<String>();

 Manager m=new Manager();
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_, container, false);


   list=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myList);

   for(Restorant r : m.getResByCity("nyc"))
   {
       restorants.add(r.getName());
   }
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.item_list, R.id.restorantItem,restorants);  

list.setAdapter(adapter);



    return rootView;
}
public void makeChange(String s)
{
    restorants.remove(0);


    ((ArrayAdapter)list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

}
}
```

While calling the method `makeChange()` i have checked that the restorants items are removing so that there is no problem with calling the method

`makeChange()` is called from my `mainActivity` that contains `viewpager` where this `fragment` is contained in the `viewpager`.

Comment: I don't see where is your adapter changing? you change the ArrayList restourants, but not the adapter.

Comment: when i call notifydatasetchange , i think that if retorants are changed then the listview have to refresh and re-add the restorants ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the element from the dataset you  provided  to the adapter,

```
adapter.remove(s)
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#remove%28T%29) you can find the documentation

Comment: there is no change in the listview :(

Comment: i only added adapter.remove(restorants.get(0)) just to find if something will happen , but nothing happen. Did i made a mistake?